# adjusting settings in liquid shopify theme

Tags: shopify, liquid

i have a question about liquid that i imagine someone here will be able to answer. im messing around with my shopify theme and wanted to change the estimated ship date on a per product basis instead of sitewide estimate of like 10-20 days after the current date. i found in my product templete.liquid that it assigns the "estimateStartDate" to equal "settings.delivery_start". "estimateStartDate" is hten references later where it is used in the product description to show estiamted ship date. there is also an assigned estimateenddate.

so my question is: where can i find the code to adjust the dates within this "settings.delivery_start" that the "esitmatestartdate" is set to? ive already made an alternate templete that i will use for the products i want to have these different shipping times. hopefully all this makes sense, im an absoulte ameature in liquid and programming in gneneral. thanks a ton in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, at the end of a template liquid file, you'll find a {% schema %} tag and a JSON with template's settings.
Looks like this:

```
{% schema %}
{
  "name": "Collection Mixed Products",
  "settings": [

    {
        "type": "checkbox",
        "id": "display_image_cat",
        "label": "Display Image Category?",
        "default": true
      },
...
  ]
}
```

This is where you should find "settings.delivery_start" and update it, if it's a template attribute.